# Versioned Transaction can't sign or serialize

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, versionedtransactions

I'm trying to sign a VersionedTransaction using Solana Wallet Adapter and getting

`TypeError: Blob.encode[data] requires (length 40) Uint8Array as src`

My code:

```
            const tx = new TransactionMessage({
                payerKey: publicKey,
                recentBlockhash,
                instructions: ixG
            })
            let preSignedTx = new VersionedTransaction(tx.compileToV0Message());
            signTransaction ? await signTransaction(preSignedTx) : alert("Error");
```

I was able to create a legacy tx and sign that fine, don't know what the error is for V0 tx.

Comment: [Check this repository for versioned transactions, it helped me a lot.](https://github.com/solana-developers/web3-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the current situation is, but at the time when we were implementing versioned transactions, they weren't supported by the majority of wallets. We tested our implementation with Phantom and Solflare because they were among the few wallets that supported versioned transactions. Also make sure you have recent version of @solana/wallet-adapter packages, check  https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md for more details...